# Query multiple collections with different fields in solr

Tags: solr

Given the following (single core) query's:

```
http://localhost/solr/a/select?indent=true&q=*:*&rows=100&start=0&wt=json
http://localhost/solr/b/select?indent=true&q=*:*&rows=100&start=0&wt=json
```

The first query returns "numFound":40000"
The second query returns "numFound":10000"

I tried putting these together by:

```
   http://localhost/solr/a/select?indent=true&shards=localhost/solr/a,localhost/solr/b&q=*:*&rows=100&start=0&wt=json
```

Now I get "numFound":50000".
The only problem is "a" has more columns than "b". So the multiple collections request only returns the values of a.

Is it possible to query multiple collections with different fields? Or do they have to be the same? And how should I change my third url to get this result?

Comment: Did you mean "b" has more columns than "a"? If the columns of "b" is a subset of those in "a" - as I understand your question - I do not understand the issue here.

Answer (score 26):

What you need is - what I call - a *unification core*. That schema itself will have no content, it is only used as a sort of wrapper to unify those fields you want to display from both cores. In there you will need

- a schema.xml that wraps up all the fields that you want to have in your unified result
- a query handler that combines the two different cores for you

An important restriction beforehand taken from [the Solr Wiki page about DistributedSearch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)

> Documents must have a unique key and the unique key must be stored (stored="true" in schema.xml) The unique key field must be unique across all shards. If docs with duplicate unique keys are encountered, Solr will make an attempt to return valid results, but the behavior may be non-deterministic.

As example, I have *shard-1* with the fields id, title, description and *shard-2* with the fields id, title, abstractText. So I have these schemas

**schema of shard-1**

```xml
<schema name="shard-1" version="1.5">

  <fields>
    <field name="id"
          type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="title" 
          type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="description"
          type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  </fields>
  <!-- type definition left out, have a look in github -->
</schema>
```

**schema of shard-2**

```xml
<schema name="shard-2" version="1.5">

  <fields>
    <field name="id" 
      type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="title" 
      type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="abstractText" 
      type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  </fields>
  <!-- type definition left out, have a look in github -->
</schema>
```

To unify these schemas I create a third schema that I call *shard-unification*, which contains all four fields.

```xml
<schema name="shard-unification" version="1.5">

  <fields>
    <field name="id" 
      type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="title" 
      type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="abstractText" 
      type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="description" 
      type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  </fields>
  <!-- type definition left out, have a look in github -->
</schema>
```

Now I need to make use of this combined schema, so I create a query handler in the solrconfig.xml of the solr-unification core

```xml
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="qf">id title description abstractText</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    <str name="mm">100%</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
<queryParser name="edismax" class="org.apache.solr.search.ExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin" />
```

That's it. Now some index-data is required in shard-1 and shard-2. To query for a unified result, just query shard-unification with appropriate shards param.

```
http://localhost/solr/shard-unification/select?q=*:*&rows=100&start=0&wt=json&shards=localhost/solr/shard-1,localhost/solr/shard-2
```

This will return you a result like

```js
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":10},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "title":"title 1",
        "description":"description 1",
        "score":1.0},
      {
        "id":2,
        "title":"title 2",
        "abstractText":"abstract 2",
        "score":1.0}]
  }}
```

## Fetch the origin shard of a document

If you want to fetch the originating shard into each document, you just need to specify `[shard]` within `fl`. Either as parameter with the query or within the requesthandler's defaults, see below. The brackets are mandatory, they will also be in the resulting response.

```xml
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="qf">id title description abstractText</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score,[shard]</str>
    <str name="mm">100%</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
<queryParser name="edismax" class="org.apache.solr.search.ExtendedDismaxQParserPlugin" />
```

## Working Sample

If you want to see a running example, checkout [my solrsample project](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample) on github and [execute the ShardUnificationTest](https://github.com/chriseverty/solrsample/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cheffe/solrsample/ShardUnificationTest.java). I have also included the shard-fetching by now.

Comment: How do you know which id(from which shard) is returned?

Comment: @Vincent I have included a paragraph about it, you can fetch the shard's URLs. That should serve the purpose.

Comment: Now I have data like this: "shard-1{id:'1'; title:'test1',description:'test1Des'}, shard-2{id:'1'; title:'test2',abstractText:'test2Des'}; URL : http://localhost/solr/shard-unification/select?q=id:1&rows=100&start=0&wt=json&shards=localhost/solr/shard-1,localhost/solr/shard-2. How to merge the result?

Comment: @OliviaWang As I have quoted at the beginning of the answer this approach requires _unique_ ids across the shards. Probably you want to perform a Join? I think this will lead off topic ... own question?

Comment: @Vincent If your sample result does not join the result, what is the meaning of searching across the two shards? Now I have this requirement, so I should join the result, how can I implement it?

Comment: The meaning of doing such a thing is comparable to a SQL UNION we use it. Does @Vincent have such a requirement with different ids? If so, I didn't see that, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Shards should be used in Solr

> When an index becomes too large to fit on a single system, or when a single query takes too long to execute

so the number and names of the columns should always be the same. This is specified in this document (where the previous quote also come from):
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

If you leave your query as it is and make the two shards with the same fields this shoudl just work as expected.

If you want more info about how the shards work in SolrCould have a look at this docuemtn also:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud

Comment: If all shards belong to the same collection, you are correct. And in fact, there are *always* the same columns in the same collection because columns are defined in the schema belonging to the collection. However, the question is how to "query multiple collections". And in different collections you may have different sets of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The collection parameter allows you to specify a collection or a number of collections on which the query should be executed. This allows you to query multiple collections at once and the features of Solr which work in a distributed manner will work across collections.

---

This documentation is for 9.4, but I tested it on 6.6 and it works.

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/solrcloud-distributed-requests.html#collection-parameter