# Solr - search multiple core return one result set?

Tags: solr

I've a core that stored all the services(along with service details) we provided then I've another core that store the services the members used with service id, member id, amount, etc.

So when a member go to this service history page I want to display the amount and service details so the data are actually from two cores.

Is there a way I can do 1 query search then it will get the data from the two core?

If this is in mysql I could do that by join the two table in the query but not sure how to do that in solr?

Please don't suggest to change to mysql as I cannot change and not what I'm asking.

Hope there's a solution? Thanks.

Comment: "Is there a way I can do 1 query search then it will get the data from the two core?" - Yes, it is called `sharding`. Please see the following link for more information - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

Comment: the join query is not supported in a distributed search, so I think you will have to do 2 queries

Comment: David, using sharding can still search two core even different schema?

Comment: Have a read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313910/query-multiple-collections-with-different-fields-in-solr