# Solr: Querying across multiple collection with different conditions

Tags: solr

I have multiple collections with schemas almost same. I'd like to apply certain conditions specific to each collection while other conditions are same across all collections and return a combined result set. Is this possible in Solr? Appreciate if you can share a sample query. I'm using Solr 5.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have issues with the "certain conditions specific to each collection", as there is no query support for anything like that. You're probably going to have do to the querying and merging yourself.

Otherwise as possible solution would be the "shard unification" strategy as mentioned in [Query multiple collections with different fields in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313910/query-multiple-collections-with-different-fields-in-solr), but scoring between documents would be local to each shard.