# Querying Solr multiple indexes with different schema in single query

Tags: solr, distributed

We have a situation where we are keeping two indexes with different schemas.

For example: suppose we have an index for seller where the key value is seller id and other attributes are seller information. Now another index is book where book id is unique key and it keeps book related information.

Is it possible to query both these indexes in a single query and get collective results?

I have checked Solr but as per my findings we can do this through distributed search in Solr but it works on same kind of schema being distributed in at max 3 indexes.

I am a newbie to Solr so please ignore if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about what makes sense for a search query but there are some rules.

The first requirement is that the **unique keys need to have the same name and be unique across collections** or Solr cannot collate results.

If you are then hoping to get some kind of sensible ranking of your results **you need some common fields**. For example I have two collections: one of product data and one containing product related documents. I have a unique key: *id* and I have *common title and contents fields* for when I want to query across the two collections. I also have an advanced search interface where I can query on specific fields like product id.

A "unification core" is a typical way of handling search across two or more cores, see this Stack Overflow answer on how to set that up

[Query multiple collections with different fields in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313910/query-multiple-collections-with-different-fields-in-solr)

Other techniques are to use federated search with something like Carrot or to issue two queries and show the results in different tabs in the search results.

Comment: Thank you David.. It might help in my problem.