# Solr - schema per user group

Tags: performance, join, solr, schema

currently I'm developing user-search application where users can do a full-text search. It should be extremely fast and there can be a lot of users, like 100.000. There are also like 10.000 user groups. Now I came across Solr and started to implement this, but it seems like I'm failing at the design level.

The requirements:

- There is a default schema which is applied to all user groups
- Each user is assigned to exactly one user group
- A user group can have additional fields (besides the default schema) which should be displayed in the result set (so they can extend the data with custom data)
- The search should be extremely fast

How would you realize that application that suits the requirements?

First, I thought about creating a "master core" for the default schema and create a core for each user group, so that I could join the necessary cores when a user requests the data. But it seems like that joining cores in standalone would not work because it does not support sharding. However, even if it would work, I'm concerned about performance because of joining at query time.

SolrCloud does seem to support sharding, but again, I would need to join the queries to one result set which would impact performance again. Additionally, I came across this post [Query multiple collections with different fields in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313910/query-multiple-collections-with-different-fields-in-solr) which says that I would need a merged schema (share-unification) to be able to query across collections/shards. So this would mean: whenever a user group's schema is changed, I would need to change my share-unifacation. As all user group's schemas rely on the share-unification, the search would be unavailable because I would need to re-index at least two schemas.

A simple solution would be to put everything into a single core (standalone) or collection (cloud), but this feels overwhelming.

Has someone did something similar before and can give a good advice or even a best practice?

Comment: Usually you don't have to edit the schema explicitly when it's dynamic for each user group, but instead use dynamic fields so you can do map it real time in your application. However, joining in Solr only works for _filtering_; it will not let you retrieve content from both sides of the join - so if you want to retrieve the content, you're going to have to do that in two separate operations in that case. If you can have both filtering requirements on both sides of your join, you can use streaming expressions to merge the content after querying both collections/cores.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So joining is not what I want if it's just filtering. What's the difference between "you're going to have to do that in two separate operations in that case" and "you can use streaming expressions to merge the content after querying both collections/cores"? Do I assume it correctly that the first one implies merging two calls to solr in my backend (which would dramatically reduce performance) while the second one implies that streaming expressions are capable of merging the two results? However, I feel unfortunate about merging at all as it feels more like a database.

Comment: If you're going to keep the data in separate collections, merging is what you'll have to do anyway - either you do it in your backend code from two queries or you let Solr do it in a streaming expression for you (which should be efficient enough as long as you can filter the query results before merging - so that you only get the documents that are relevant on both sides of the merge). However, the second option is to merge everything into a single document, but that document will be rather large with so many possible groups. How many groups will have custom values for a given document?

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks, so I guess the second option is what I'm going for, I will have a closer look into streaming expressions. Each user group can add additional fields, as many as they want, it's not limited.
You can image it like this: 
There are master data fields which are displayed at frontend in a grid. Each user group can add custom columns (solr fields) to that grid, so they can provide extra data per row or data set. The custom fields can also be searchable by full-text search.

Comment: Yes, I understood that point - but it'll be a (major) difference in document size if there usually are three additional fields added to a document or five fields for 8000 user groups (if most user groups have a custom value added). If the set of custom fields are rather sparse, having them on the documents themselves could be a viable solution.

Comment: Approximately, there will be more than 10 million documents (assumed that document is a date entry). I see your point and I agree as I can't imagine having thousands of extra fields in one core is suitable. I'm about to do some performance tests right now, merging two cores at the backend together, but I guess the performance will not be good enough. The result should be returned within 1-2 seconds.
"you can use streaming expressions to merge the content after querying both collections/cores" - Could you give an example of how such an expression would look like? You seem to be expeirenced.

Comment: If there are only a few - hundred extra fields in the document, handling 10m documents on a single core should be very doable; doing it with a few nodes in a collection setup should be more than enough and scalable. With streaming expressions you'd have to `search` calls (with identical filtering and sorting), and then use a `hashJoin` between those two searches to get a merged document out. You can use differenting merging functions to get different behaviors.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you help!